# Entity Framework FK error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My code is returning the following error:

> The property 'cartID' cannot be configured as a navigation property.
>   The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have
>   a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type
>   must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

My model is below:

```
[Table("ShoppingCarts")]
public class ShoppingCart 
{
    [Key]
    public string cartID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}


[Table("ShoppingCartItems")]
public class ShoppingCartItem
{


    private string cartDisplayImg;

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Cart Item ID#")]
    public int cartItemID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cart ID")]
    [ForeignKey("cartID")]
    public string cartID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string itemTitle { get; set; }

    public int listingID { get; set; }
    public int sellerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string itemType { get; set; }

    public string condition { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string displayImgPath
    {

        get {
           cartDisplayImg = "http://www.example.com/Images/Phones/" + Make + "-" + Model + "-1.jpg";

           return cartDisplayImg;

        }

    }
    public decimal lineTotal
    {
        get {
            decimal cartLineTotal = Price * Quantity;
            return cartLineTotal; 
        }

    }

}

public class ShopingCartContext : DbContext
{

    public ShopingCartContext()
        : base("PHONEOUTLET_DBConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ShopingCartContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ShopingCartContext>());

    }


    public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCart { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I guess that is because cartID is a string? try to change it to int
and add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] after [Key] for auto generation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ForeignKey`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) data annotation must be used on the FK property along with information telling it which navigation property represents the relationship it is a foreign key for:

```
[Table("ShoppingCartItems")]
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
   //..
   [Display(Name = "Cart ID")]
   [ForeignKey("Shoppingcart")]
   public string cartID { get; set; }
   public virtual ShoppingCart Shoppingcart { get; set; }
}
```

And alternatively, you can apply the `ForeignKey` annotation to the navigation property and tell it which property is the foreign key for the relationship:

```
[Table("ShoppingCartItems")]
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
   //..
   [Display(Name = "Cart ID")]
   public string cartID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("cartID")]
   public virtual ShoppingCart Shoppingcart { get; set; }
}
```

In addition, Code First has a set of [rules](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s02.html) that are applied to  locate a foreign key property when it discovers a relationship. The conventions are based on the name of the property. The foreign key property will be discovered by convention if it is named `[Target Type Key Name]`, `[Target Type Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`, or `[Navigation Property Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`. If you use the `ForeignKey` data annotation these rules will be ignored because you are telling explicitly to EF what FK property you want to use.

Comment: I agree with this solution , although I recommend promoting EF code first conventions

Comment: I'm agree with you that is important to know these conventions, but I prefer to tell explicitly to EF which are my FK property using the `ForeignKey` data annotation or using Fluent Api. Anyway, I added these conventions in my answer

Comment: Voted up for your answer

Comment: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'cartID' on type 'MySite.Models.ShoppingCartItem' is not valid. The navigation property 'Shoppingcart' was not found on the dependent type 'MySite.Models.ShoppingCartItem'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Comment: Did you add the navigation property `ShoppingCart` on your `ShopingCartItem` entity?. Look the first example, I'm sure you forgot to add the  `public virtual ShoppingCart Shoppingcart { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the type for CartID have to be an integer and not a string? I'm not sure if this would fix your issue or not, but it seems like that is what the error message is talking about.

Comment: That's not it. @mcloud you can create string PK using GUID() , it's easier. check out this conversation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250716/why-not-always-use-guids-instead-of-integer-ids

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow `EF` code conventions so instead of this

```
    [Display(Name = "Cart ID")]
    [ForeignKey("cartID")]
    public string cartID { get; set; }
```

Try this

```
    [Display(Name = "Cart ID")]
    public string CartID { get; set; }
    public virtual ShoppingCart Shoppingcart { get; set; }
```

A common way to define one to many relationships in classes is to have a child collection in the one class and then a foreign key property along with a navigation property in the child class.

---

**EDIT 1:**
Try to follow `EF` code conventions. Please refer to this article for more info :[Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)